# SQL - An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list

Tags: sql

I just want to update my TicketStatus column if reached its 7 days prior to latest DatePosted, error is displayed when adding MAX in my Dateposted.

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.TicketStatus = @Status
FROM    TicketTb a
        LEFT JOIN TicketConvo b
            ON b.TicketID= a.TicketNumber
            where  DATEDIFF(day,MAX(b.DatePosted),GetDate() ) >= 7
```

Comment: share sample data and output

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (UPDATE FROM is not included in ANSI/ISO SQL.)

Answer (score 2):

Use having with group by

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.TicketStatus = @Status
FROM    TicketTb a
        LEFT JOIN TicketConvo b
            ON b.TicketID= a.TicketNumber group by a.TicketNumber
            having  DATEDIFF(day,MAX(b.DatePosted),GetDate() ) >= 7
```

Comment: How does an answer like this get an upvote?  I understand the attempt but the SQL is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

**try this:**

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.TicketStatus = @Status
FROM    TicketTb a
        LEFT JOIN ( select TicketID,MAX(b.DatePosted) as DatePosted TicketConvo  group by TicketID )b
            ON b.TicketID= a.TicketNumber
            where  DATEDIFF(day,DatePosted ,GetDate() ) >= 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this dml script.

```
UPDATE  TicketTb
SET     TicketStatus = @Status
WHERE  TicketNumber in (Select a.TicketNumber FROM TicketTb a
                            LEFT JOIN TicketConvo b
                            ON b.TicketID= a.TicketNumber
                            GROUP BY a.TicketNumber
                            HAVING  DATEDIFF(day,MAX(b.DatePosted),GetDate() ) >= 7)
```